# Smart x-axis for bokeh periodic time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, bokeh

I have time series data in a pandas Series object.  The values are floats representing the size of an event.  Together, event times and sizes tell me how busy my system is.  I'm using a scatterplot.

I want to look at traffic patterns over various time periods, to answer questions like "Is there a daily spike at noon?" or "Which days of the week have the most traffic?"  Therefore I need to overlay data from many different periods.  I do this by converting timestamps to timedeltas (first by subtracting the start of the first period, then by doing a mod with the period length).

Now my index uses time intervals relative to an "abstract" time period, like a day or a week.  I would like to produce plots where the x-axis shows something other than just nanoseconds.  Ideally it would show month, day of the week, hour, etc. depending on timescale as you zoom in and out (as Bokeh graphs generally do for time series).

The code below shows an example of how I currently plot.  The resulting graph has an x-axis in units of nanoseconds, which is not what I want.  How do I get a smart x-axis that behaves more like what I would see for timestamps?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

oneDay = np.timedelta64(24*60*60,'s')
fourHours = 24000000000000 # four hours in nanoseconds (ugly)

time = [pd.Timestamp('2015-04-27 01:00:00'),  # a Monday
        pd.Timestamp('2015-05-04 02:00:00'),  # a Monday
        pd.Timestamp('2015-05-11 03:00:00'),  # a Monday
        pd.Timestamp('2015-05-12 04:00:00')   # a Tuesday
        ]
resp = [2.0, 1.3, 2.6, 1.3]

ts = pd.Series(resp, index=time)
days = dict(list(ts.groupby(lambda x: x.weekday)))
monday = days[0]  # this TimeSeries consists of all data for all Mondays

# Now convert timestamps to timedeltas
# First subtract the timestamp of the starting date
# Then take the remainder after dividing by one day
# Result: each index value is in the 24 hour range [00:00:00, 23:59:59]
tdi = monday.index - pd.Timestamp(monday.index.date[0])
x = pd.TimedeltaIndex([td % oneDay for td in tdi])
y = monday.values

output_file('bogus.html')
xmax = fourHours  # why doesn't np.timedelta64 work for xmax?
fig = figure(x_range=[0,xmax], y_range=[0,4])
fig.circle(x, y)
show(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jianxun Li, but your answer is not what I need.  I want the x-axis to behave similarly to the class bokeh.models.axes.DatetimeAxis.  That class uses a bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter, which formats x-ticks differently at different scales.  It "knows" about weekdays, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.  I can't use this directly, because my x values are timedeltas, not datetimes.  I will keep digging on this and post what I find here.